# Problem with converting response from Http request

Tags: angular, http

I have this HTTP request:

```
storeCategory(file: File, category: CategoryModel): Observable<HttpEvent<{}>> {
    const formdata: FormData = new FormData();
    console.log("1")
    formdata.append('file', file);
    formdata.append('category', new Blob([JSON.stringify({ "category_name": category.category_name, "category_description": category.category_description })], { type: "application/json" }))
    const url = `api/cateogry/saveCategory`;
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', url, formdata, {
      reportProgress: true,
      responseType: 'text'
    });
    return this.http.request<CategoryModel>(req);
  }
```

From this method I send data and image, and my backend method returns a JSON-object, but I want to bind that object as a `CategoryModel`, but now it is bound to `HttpEvent`.

My callback :
[image]
Another image:
[image]

Another image:
[image]

Comment: Your return type is `Observable<HttpEvent<{}>>`, maybe that is why? You can change it to `Observable<CategoryModel>`?

Comment: When I do that I have error:
`Type 'Observable<HttpEvent<CategoryModel>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<CategoryModel>'.
  Type 'HttpEvent<CategoryModel>' is not assignable to type 'CategoryModel'.
    Type 'HttpSentEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'CategoryModel': id, category_name, category_description, image_path, products`

Comment: Does it work if you add this as well: `this.http.request<CategoryModel>(req).body` // added body. Some documentation here: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest

Comment: Part `.body` I do not understand well? What is `.body`?

Comment: Sorry to ask but ...Is there not success callback of http request?

Comment: From the docs, `body` is a property on a HttpRequest, which is of the same type as you use in the http request (CategoryModel), and contains the data from the request.

Comment: you have to convert json data to object.

Comment: I have success callback of HTTP request, I need to convert JSON data to the object. you can see how to look my callback in the post, I add the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the image you posted, it seems the request is not a `CategoryModel`, but a list of `CategoryModel`s inside a `HttpResponse`-object. Since you are using `http.request`, you will get many responses, and each have a different `HttpEventType` [found here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpEventType#ResponseHeader). You need to filter the response for each type, and get the content you want based on the type (e.g. `event.type === HttpEventType.Response`).

Try this:

```
storeCategory(file: File, category: CategoryModel): Observable<CategoryModel[]> {
    const formdata: FormData = new FormData();
    console.log("1")
    formdata.append('file', file);
    formdata.append('category', new Blob([JSON.stringify({ "category_name": category.category_name, "category_description": category.category_description })], { type: "application/json" }))
    const url = `api/cateogry/saveCategory`;
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', url, formdata, {
      reportProgress: true,
      responseType: 'text'
    });
    return this.http.request<any>(req).pipe(map(event => {
     console.log("event",event);
     if(event.type == HttpEventType.Response){ // try different event types based on desired result.
      event.body = event.body.replace(/\\/g,"/"); // replace all double backslashes with slash.
      return <CategoryModel[]>JSON.parse(event.body); // try to parse the data if it is a string
     }
    }));
  }
```

I changed the return type of the method to be `Observable<CategoryModel[]>`, and changed the return statement to convert the result to reflect that.

remember to `import {map} from 'rxjs/operators'` in your component
remember to `import {HttpEventType} from '@angular/common/http'` in your component

And also have a look at the example from the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/http)

The different `HttpEventType`s can be found [here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpEventType#ResponseHeader)

Comment: Thanks, but I have a problem with `partialText`. This is my error:
`Property 'partialText' does not exist on type 'HttpEvent<any>'.
  Property 'partialText' does not exist on type 'HttpSentEvent'`

Comment: I added some changes that might help. I think you need to do `event.body.partialText`, and filter based on the type of event. I think the `HttpEventType.Response` is the correct one. Try to do a `console.log("event",event")` and see how it looks like. It might be easier to know what to return

Comment: Sorry, but I have a problem with  `partialText`:
`Property 'partialText' does not exist on type 'CategoryModel[]'.`

Comment: I made some edits: `return this.http.request<any>(req).pipe(map(event => {` I changed `CategoryModel[]` to `any` inside the return statement.

Comment: Now do not receive anything how response.

Comment: do you log the event? Can you see how it looks like? I think the event will be logged around 3 times? Can you post what the event is logging? Can you try to use if `(event.type === HttpEventType.DownloadProgress)` instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189675/discussion-between-john-and-sin-san-sun).

Comment: @SInsansun did my updated answer work? Please let me know in the chat if you still have problems. I added `JSON.parse(event.body);`

Comment: Finally this work. Great job man, this is very helpful  I appreciate a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Object of Class `CategoryModel` and pass the params in constructor.

```
let resp = new CategoryModel(json_object[0]);
```

Comment: That is not  possible, a have error:
`Expected 5 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)
category.model.ts(12, 40): An argument for 'category_description' was not provided.
(parameter) data: HttpEvent<{}>`

Comment: I have the array of `json_object`. I think that is a problem with this solution.

Comment: so then you can call a loop around the above statement.

Comment: Any example of this?

Comment: kindly try this `let arr = json_array.map(e => new CategoryModel(e));`

Comment: I have this now:
`Property 'map' does not exist on type 'HttpEvent<{}>'.
  Property 'map' does not exist on type 'HttpSentEvent'.ts(2339)`